# Can I programmatically take a xml layout and reuse it?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have the following button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="5dp"
android:textSize="10sp"
android:text="Button" />
```

Now in my code I want to programmatically make a dynamic amount of these buttons depending on certain factors.

Now i have spent a fair amount of time trying to get the following code to work:

```
 Button txtName = new Button(getActivity(), null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
    txtName.setClickable(false);
    txtName.setTextSize(5);
    txtName.setMaxLines(1);
    txtName.setMaxHeight(40);
    txtName.setMinHeight(0);
    txtName.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    txtName.setText(tagsList.get(i));
```

For some reason that code does not do what I want it to do. Please see my other question about that: [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775470/how-to-programmatically-make-a-small-button-wrap-small-text)

However my question now is, can I take that layout code from the button above and then use it to make duplicate buttons like you would do with a list adapter?

in other words I want one xml describing my buttons layout and I want it to be used for many buttons on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can take a xml layout from layot using this code

```
Button button=(Button)LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.buttonlayout, null);
```

and use it as you want.

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is inflating.

At the moment your approach has little use of the XML. You're creating an actual new button with some attributes from the code, not using your XML layout. 
That is fine too, btw.

Anyway, if you want to use your XML layout/button, you want to use Android's inflator:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

That would look sort of like this;

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
Button mButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
```

Now you've got your button in code, inflated from your button layout. 
If you want to add this multiple times to a certain view, you will probably want to manually set different tags or IDs to each button so you can recognize them later.

Answer (score 0):

In the same Activity no, each XML view must connect to a single view,you can however inflate billions of buttons:)

```
final Button button = new Button(this);

        button.setText(day);
        final String whichDay = day;
        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.newProgActivity);
        param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        param.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, activityTitle.getId());
        param.setMargins(0, margins, 0, 0);
        layout.addView(button, param);
```

now you can set them below each other using

```
button.setId()
```

and then the child button will get the rule below that id..
or anchor them to a single view in your xml and use `setmargins()`

Comment: You can inflate a certain XML view as often as you'd like.

Comment: you can... but if its a part of an activity XML and you use 6 buttons with the same id ull have a problem...

Comment: So you use setId() and his question is talking about a separate button layout :)

Comment: ooooo...i thought the button layout was a part of a larger XML